System Freezes after installing Nvidia drivers
Ubuntu 22.04.4
GPU: GeForce Rtx 4060
Dell G15-5530 (dualboot windows 11 and ubuntu)
Tried everthing from reinstalling drivers/ubuntu to downgrading kernal and bios versions. Nothing works.
Tried using different Nvidia driver verions eg: 550, 535, 470 etc.
also tried opensource nouveau also.
every time result is same system freezes and unable to access it.
everything works fine in windows.
Tried using sudo apt install nvidia-driver-470
also tried using Additional Drivers app.
every time it freezes i installed fresh ubuntu (also tried on ubuntu 20)

Please edit the question and include the exact steps you did to change NVIDIA driver versions.

I have the same Dell laptop and I am suffering from the same issues. Every time a software app or OS tool tries to access the Nvidia gfx card, the system hangs or crashes.
One thing that worked for me was to use X-Windows instead of Wayland - at least, I can boot successfully. You can choose X-Windows on the login screen when you click on your name; you will see a small settings icon in the lower right corner, where you can select Wayland /X-Windows
I also disabled SecureBoot in order to avoid any issues with the UEFI rejecting the Nvidia driver during startup.
Under no circumstance must you disable the hybrid gfx card in the UEFI settings - the laptop is using Nvidia Optimus, where the Nvidia card will only work in tandem with the Intel i915 card.
